# How to print/display current search criteria into PDF using Yii2 and mpdf?

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, mpdf

I've been trying to implement MPDF over the search function from Yii2 advanced template but doesn't seem to give the result I've wanted.

What I want is when I put the value inside the `textField(sales_id)`, I should be able to operate Print Button using MPDF extension where the condition is that the data showed in mpdf should only contains similar sales_id value in it's fields, like this image below:

[image: view example]

I made the method in my controller like so:

```
public function actionPrintPerSales()
    {
        // trying to get the sales_id post value
        $request = Yii::$app->request;
        $sales_id = $request->post('sales_id');
        $model = new PiutangCustomer();



    // Your SQL query filter here
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => PiutangCustomer::find()
            ->where(['status_piutang' => '0'])
            ->andWhere(['sales_id'] => $sales_id)
            ->orderBy(['customer_id' => SORT_ASC])
    ]);

    $content = $this->renderPartial('_print-per-sales', ['model', 'dataProvider' => $dataProvider]);

    // setup kartik\mpdf\Pdf component
    $pdf = new Pdf([
    // set to use core fonts only
    'mode' => Pdf::MODE_CORE,
    // A4 paper format
    'format' => Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
    // portrait orientation
    'orientation' => Pdf::ORIENT_PORTRAIT,
    // stream to browser inline
    'destination' => Pdf::DEST_BROWSER,
    // your html content input
    'content' => $content,
    // format content from your own css file if needed or use the
    // enhanced bootstrap css built by Krajee for mPDF formatting
    'cssFile' => '@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.min.css',
    // any css to be embedded if required
    'cssInline' => '.kv-heading-1{font-size:18px}',
    // set mPDF properties on the fly
    'options' => ['title' => 'Cetak Laporan Piutang Menurut Customer'],
    // call mPDF methods on the fly
    'methods' => [
    'SetHeader'=>['Laporan Piutang - NAMA TOKO / PERUSAHAAN / CV'],
    'SetFooter'=>['Powered by PFSOFT | {PAGENO}'],
    ]
    ]);

    /*------------------------------------*/
    Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_RAW;
    $headers = Yii::$app->response->headers;
    $headers->add('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
    /*------------------------------------*/

    // return the pdf output as per the destination setting
    return $pdf->render();
    }
```

For the View I made something like this:

```
<?php echo $this->render('_search-per-sales', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>
```

And the sub-form _search-per-sales View:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'action' => ['print-per-sales'],
        'method' => 'post',
    ]); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'sales_id')->textInput() ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'PRINT'), ['class' => 'fa fa-print btn btn-warning']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

And as for the rendered view from the actionPrintPerSales  (_print-per-sales) :

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        //'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            // 'customer_id',
            [
                'label' => 'Nama Customer',
                'value' => 'customer.first_name',
            ],
            [
                'attribute' => 'nilai_piutang',
                'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'text-align:right'],
                'format'=>['decimal',0],
            ],
            [
                'attribute' => 'total_bayar',
                'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'text-align:right'],
                'format'=>['decimal',0]
            ],
            [
                'attribute' => 'sisa_piutang',
                'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'text-align:right'],
                'format'=>['decimal',0]
            ],
            'faktur',
            [
                'attribute' => 'tanggal_jatuh_tempo',
                'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'text-align:center'],
                'format' => ['date', 'php:d-M-Y']
            ],
            'sales_id',
            [
                'label' => 'Nama Sales',
                'value' => function ($data){ return $data->kodeSales->nama; },
            ],  
        ],
    ]); ?>
```

There's something wrong with my SQL query filter, inside controller. I can tell my mpdf is working because when I comment out the where clause:

```
// ->andWhere('sales_id' = $sales_id)
```

The pdf is working, only it shows all the data without filtering sales_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use

```
  ->andFilterWhere(['sales_id' => $model->sales_id ])
```

could be that you   `$sales_id = $request->post('sales_id');` don't load the value as you expected ..

Comment: thanks for the help, but I got it all working by fixing the where clause ->andWhere(['sales_id'] => $model->sales_id) into ->andWhere(['sales_id' => $model->sales_id])

Comment: @JoenMarz   . is my answer  is right then mark as accepted .. otherwise if is usefull mark as  useful  ..

Comment: the array bracket should be ->andFilterWhere(['sales_id' => $model->sales_id])

Answer (score 0):

Due to the use of `ActiveForm` the variable is passed into your post as `modelName[salesid]` and not `sales_id`. You can populate the model attributes from a form using [`load`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#load()-detail):

```
$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
```

You can then filter the values via:

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => PiutangCustomer::find()
        ->where(['status_piutang' => '0'])
        ->andWhere(['sales_id'] => $model->sales_id)
        ->orderBy(['customer_id' => SORT_ASC])
]);
```

You need to pass `$model` into `renderPartial`:

```
$content = $this->renderPartial('_print-per-sales', ['model' => $model, 'dataProvider' => $dataProvider]);
```

And then pass `$model` into your form:

```
<?php echo $this->render('_search-per-sales', ['model' => $model]); ?>
```

Comment: as you can see in my controller, I already did that. My mpdf displays normally. My question above is, how to display the mpdf where the sales_id value is equal to my textField value.

Comment: You are passing the string `'model'` instead of the object `$model` i.e. `['model', ...]` instead of `['model' => $model']. I have updated the answer with other issues.

Comment: thanks for the help, but I got it all working by fixing the where clause ->andWhere(['sales_id'] => $model->sales_id) into ->andWhere(['sales_id' => $model->sales_id])